# What is NaCl Socket API?

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, websocket, google-nativeclient

I've found it at `chrome://flags/` but I don't really know what is this. I searched on the web a lot, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this, http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ . It is the eighth one down. It looks like it allows Native Client access to TCP/UDP sockets for chrome extensions

Comment: Oddly enough, I couldn't find it under `about:flags` for chromium v18. Which version are you running?

Comment: found it. I think it's just debugging for NaCl.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Is there any documentation concerning that?